# How to load windows dll in Emscripten plateform

Tags: javascript, c++, emscripten

I need load a windows dll from javascript code in my project. Is there a solution to realize it? For example, use Emscripten, but it can't load a dll in windows. If use V8, but it works only in node webkit application. I need your help.

Comment: Javascript how? Serverside with nodejs? In the browser? In a winrt app?

Comment: Which DLL and do you have the code for the DLL?

Comment: In a browser side,  use javascript to load any dll or so into the browser.